# Cannot connect to Postgres in Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose YML file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123

  admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

I cannot seem to connect to my postgres instance via pgAdmin running in the same container. Nor can I connect via the CLI.

Comment: I set this up locally and it works as expected.  Are you connecting from pgadmin to postgres using the hostname "db"?  Can you include more details about how you're connecting?

Comment: I am trying to connect via CLI or a Node.js app and I get rejected.

Comment: pgadmin has nothing to do with cli or node. It's a web ui